# Easy Congurence

Tags: number-theory

How many natural numbers $n$ are there such that $5^n$ does not leave a remainder $1$ when divided by any prime $p>3$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is equivalent to solving $5^n-1=2^a3^b$ which has finitely many solutions by Kobayashi's theorem. If $b>0$ then $n$ has to be even. Then $5^{n/2}-1$ is of the same form and hence by infinite descent we get $b=0$ . The equation becomes $5^n-1=2^a$ which has only one solution $(1,1)$ . Then by the method of descent we get $n$ has to be a power of $2$ and by inspection we deduce that $n≤2$. So we get $n=1,2$ are the only solutions.